# Inserting variable(s) into sqlite databse tkinter python

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data from variable(s) when a button is click (note: the inserting part is working with hard code, it's the variable part that's not working), into sqlite3 database in python 2.7.11 tkinter.
Here is my code:

```
    digit = 1
    color_label = 'blue'
def test():

    connection = connect(database = "shoes.db")

    best_shoes = connection.cursor()
```

> sql = "INSERT INTO Shoes(Rank, Color)VALUES(?, ?)",
>           (digit, color_label); REPLACED

```
    best_shoes.execute("INSERT INTO Top_Ten(Rank, Color)VALUES(?, ?)",                
    (digit, color_label))

    best_shoes.execute(sql)

    rows_inserted = best_shoes.rowcount

    connection.commit()

    best_shoes.close()
    connection.close()


    return rows_inserted

save = Button(window, text = 'Save', command=test)
save.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

edit: I'm getting this error by the way: 
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: What is `digit` and what is `color_label`?

Comment: Both are my variables that im trying to insert into the database, digit is any number, so lets go with 1 and color_label again is any color so lets go with 'blue' for this.

Comment: So, they are literally something like `1` and `"bluie"`, or are they an object or `StringVar` or `Entry` widget?

Comment: To begin with i just want to enter variables into a database once i cross that step it should be ok so iv'e used digit and color_label as an example, if i can get them into the database it should be ok. But actually im using a for loop to retrieve data from a website and place tthe data into grids, so i have that working but now i want to insert that data into a database.

Comment: Aha, so i fixed that error by changing my insert statement to be like this: best_shoes.execute("INSERT INTO Top_Ten(Rank, Color)VALUES(?, ?)",(digit, color_label))       But now... i'm getting InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. ?

Comment: We will have to have the complete error message, with the offending line included, to help.  For example, you may or may not have an error on the "connection" line depending on your import statement.  Also, we have no idea what the types of "Rank" and "Color" are.